# How can I have subsection headers in a separate column while maintaining document structure and control of fonts?

Tags: sectioning

I am trying to typeset a document (a CV) so that subsection headings (and only those) are in a separate column to the left. I would also like to be able to control the fonts for content and headings (I usually use `fontspec`, `sectsty` and XeTeX for this), and maintain the "usual" document structure so that eg. pandoc can still parse it.

The [`parcolumns`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns?lang=en) package is out, because it affects document structure too much (which is fair, it wasn't designed for this use).

I have tried the [medium length graduate CV template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-graduate-cv), but that has *section* headings hard coded in numerous places, and won't play nice with the `sectsty` package, making it hard to change heading fonts. (I haven't given up on this, but it's hard enough that I feel like I'm barking up the wrong tree.)

Here's a picture of roughly what I'm aiming for: [image: Example of subsection header in different column]

What is a straightforward way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Dimensions

\textwidth=13cm
\oddsidemargin=4cm
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\topmargin=-1cm
\textheight=25cm

\makeatletter

\def\section#1{\vspace{1cm plus 5mm minus 3mm}\goodbreak\par\noindent%
    \hspace{-4cm}\parbox{17cm}{\Large\bf #1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}\@xsect{0.5\baselineskip}}

\def\subsection#1{\vspace{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}\par\noindent%
    \hspace{-4cm}\vbox to 0pt{\smash{\parbox[t][][b]{3.7cm}{%
    \large\noindent\raggedleft #1%
    \addcontentsline{entoc}{subsection}{#1}}}}%
    \@xsect{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}}% This requires tweaking to vertically align the text corrrectly

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Second subsection with a lot of text}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Second subsection with a lot of text}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Compilation result]

To align the title to the full text width, the `calc` package is useful:

```
\usepackage{calc}
```

Then after the dimensions block, add:

```
\newlength{\fullwidth}
\setlength{\fullwidth}{\textwidth+\oddsidemargin}
```

...and within the `\makeatletter` block, do:

```
\def\maketitle{%
    \noindent\hspace{-\oddsidemargin}%
    \begin{minipage}{\fullwidth}%
        \begin{center}%
            {\LARGE\@title}%
        \end{center}%
    \end{minipage}}
```

`fontspec` commands will need to be inserted into the (sub)section command definitions themselves (ie. don't use `titlesec` or `sectsty` commands for those):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\subsectionfont{Some Font}

[...]

\def\subsection#1{\vspace{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}\par\noindent%
    \hspace{-4cm}\vbox to 0pt{\smash{\parbox[t][][b]{3.7cm}{%
    \large\noindent\raggedleft\subsectionfont #1%
```

Finally, if you use `hyperref` to get a PDF index, you'll need to add `\phantomsection` commands to avoid your page numbers being wrong:

```
    \large\noindent\raggedleft #1%
    \phantomsection%
```

Comment: This is great! Much simpler than hacking on `res.cls`. One quibble: the ragged right alignment of the subsections doesn't seem to be doing what I'd expect (right alignment, no justification).

Comment: Also the document title seems to shift across to align with the text, even though both margins are equal. What causes that?

Comment: @detly, '\raggedright' means that text would be aligned by *left*. To make document title you can redefine `\maketitle` or put it into minipage: `\noindent\hspace{-4cm}\begin{minipage}{17cm}
\maketitle
\end{minipage}`

Comment: Hah, I just needed `\raggedleft` there. I'll fiddle with the title to get it right. Finally, is there a foolproof way to vertically align the top of the subsection heading and the paragraph text? Or is it just trial and error with the measurements?

Comment: I've edited your answer with all the tweaks and notes I used to neaten things up.

Comment: It would be better to use `geometry` for the layout. This will not necessarily result in a document whose layout matches the paper size. I would either stick to `titlesec` or jettison it. Loading it and then competing with it doesn't make much sense to me.